# jquery validation, make fields conditionally required?

Tags: jquery, validation

Using the jQuery plugin found here:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

I have a form, that when certain checkboxes are selected, additional fields are shown to the user. I would like to make these fields required when they click the checkbox, and unrequired if they unselect it.

Is there a way to dynamically set requirements for elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think simplest approach is to attach the "required" class using jquery to these elements on click.

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on the answer above by K2so:

If you put something like this in the document ready:

```
$("#reasonCode").change(reasonCodeChange);
```

where the element with id reasonCode is equivalent to your checkboxes. On change, it calls the function reasonCodeChange...

```
function reasonCodeChange(){

var strValue = $("#reasonCode option:selected").text()


strValue = strValue.substring(0,2);
    if(strValue== "7." || strValue== "9." || strValue== "10" ||strValue== "11" || strValue== "12"){
        $('#reasonCodeExpRow').addClass('showMe');
        $('#reasonCodeExp').addClass('required');
        $('#reasonCodeExpRow').removeClass('hideMe');
    }else{
        $('#reasonCodeExpRow').addClass('hideMe');
        $('#reasonCodeExp').removeClass('required');
        $('#reasonCodeExpRow').removeClass('showMe');

    };
}
```

And that should be plenty to get you going. The hideMe and showMe classes are self explanatory :)